# star symbols in gnuplot

Tags: character-encoding, gnuplot, symbols, postscript, figure

I'm trying to generate an .eps figure in `gnuplot` using

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color solid
```

I want to include in my figure a title for a plot containing some star symbols, e.g ★ ☆

I tried through this:

```
plot "./mydata" u 1:2 title "★ ☆"
```

as well as this:

```
stars = sprintf("★ ☆")
plot "./mydata" u 1:2 title stars
```

but both of them don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It displays perfectly if I use the pdf terminal `set term pdf; set output 'plot.pdf'`.  It also works if I convert the .pdf to .ps, but the .ps doesn't look that great.  Looking at the code for the .eps generated by gnuplot, the star symbols are there all right where they should be; they just aren't displayed.  It doesn't seem to be a font issue because several fonts behave the same.

Comment: @andyras -- (from what I've read) unicode support in postscript is sketchy at best.  Layer gnuplot on top of that and you're in for disappointment ... As you point out, if `pdf` is an option, then maybe that's the way to go here.

Comment: Thank you andyras! It works, but I wanted a postscript (EPS format)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set term postscript enh color eps
set output 'test.eps'
set title 'star1:{/ZapfDingbats \110} star2:{/ZapfDingbats \111}'
plot sin(x)
```

Take a look at `docs/psdoc/ps_guide.ps` which is included with the gnuplot distribution.  That's where I go when looking for special postscript characters...

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the documentation! It is what exactly I was looking for! :)